Flask app searched result in route returns previous one
I can't handle it for a long time.
it returns previous search (mySearch) when I try second one (mySecondSearch) in address - http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?key=mySearch
(but query works - I get template with list with key mySecondSearch)
how to get address with key that relevant my request
header.html
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('views.search', key=slugy) }}" role="search" class="hiddenSearch">

{{ search_form.hidden_tag() }}
<input class="form-control" type="search" 
                            placeholder="" 
                            aria-label="Search"   
                            name="searched" 
                            minlength="3" 
                            maxlength="44" 
                            oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('')" 
                            oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')" 
                            title=""/>
</form>

the view.py
@views.route('/search/', methods=["POST"])
def search():
    page_title = ""
    clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
    search_form = SearchForm()
    posts = Poems.query

    if request.method == "POST" and search_form.validate_on_submit():
        # Get Data from submitted form
        searched = search_form.searched.data
        poem_list.searched = searched
        slugy = slugify(searched)

        # Query 
        page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
        posts = posts.filter(Poems.con_keyword.ilike('%' + searched + '%'))
        posts = posts.order_by(Poems.title).paginate(per_page=7, page=page, error_out=True)

        return render_template("content/search.html", 
                       search_form=search_form, 
                       searched=searched, 
                       page_title=page_title,
                       posts=posts, 
                       clean=clean, re=re, slugy=slugy)

    else:
    flash("!")
    return render_template("content/search.html", 
                           search_form=search_form, 
                           page_title=page_title, 
                           posts=posts, clean=clean, re=re)

search.html
<section id="search">

    <div class="content">
        {% if searched %}
         <h1> you ask -
            <span class="src-ed">{{ searched[0:12] }}...</span><br/>we found:
        </h1>

...etc

I tried remove cache, or save no data,  - nothing
tested - everything return something flawlessly
AI - nothing that can help me (I tried its code - works as mine)

It is crazy but the code was taken from free courses so basically written wrongly. I've read a lot(documentation) so solution is !!! re-write it!
so now it works !
http://127.0.0.1:5000/search?key=myNewSearch
code


@views.route('/search', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
     page_title = ""
     clean = re.compile('<.*?>')
     search_form = SearchForm()
     query = request.args.get('key')

     if query:
         posts = Poems.query.filter(Poems.con_keyword.ilike(f'%{query}%')).all()
     else:
         posts = Poems.query.all()

     return render_template("content/search.html", search_form=search_form, 
                            page_title=page_title, posts=posts, 
                            clean=clean, re=re, key=query)



and of course html form should be GET
<form method="GET" action="{{url_for('views.search', key=searched)}}" 
                   role="search" 
                   class="hiddenSearch">

<input class="form-control" 
       type="search" 
       placeholder="" 
       aria-label="Search" name="key">
</form>


